# Media queries stop overwriting?

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries

### Solved

---

So - I have been building this grid-framework, when I stumbled upon an issue, which neither I had before nor I can find any evidence on online.

---

**In short**: when I have multiple `@media queries` arranged like this:

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {...}
@media (min-width: 600px) {...}
@media (min-width: 840px) {...}
```

I expect each one to overwrite these who are before it [e.g. `@media (min-width: 840px) {...}` will overwrite `@media (min-width: 600px) {...}` and `@media (min-width: 400px) {...}`] based on the current viewport.

---

I am using Sass to generate multiple `@media queries` as well as a bunch of `classes`, but its probably not to something being *wrong* in the code, but something being *missing*.

So what is this supposed to do?

The number of columns changes based on the viewport.

```
$breakpoints: (
//name  bp      col-count
  xs:   [0      4],
  sm:   [400    4],
  md:   [600    8],
  lg:   [840    12],
  xl:   [1024   12],
  xxl:  [1440   12],
);
```

Imagining I am in the `xs` breakpoint, which reaches froom `0px` to `400px`, and I have a column with the class `xs:col:11`, then I don't want it with to be `100vw / (12 / 11)` [`91.6666667`], but `100%`. So naturally I am trying to overwrite each class, **however**:

[image]

It stops overwriting after the second `@media querie`, I expect it to still be 6 columns until the `sm` breakpoint.

---

Below you can see my code and [here](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/RwajMjy) is a Codepen too.

```
$permanent-grid: true;

@mixin permanent-grid-cols($prefix, $span, $col-count) {
  .#{$prefix}\3A col\3A #{$span} {
    flex: 0 0 #{100vw / ($col-count / $span)};
    max-width: #{100vw / ($col-count / $span)};
  }       
}

@if($permanent-grid) {
  body {
    @each $breakpoint-name, $breakpoint-content in $breakpoints {
      $breakpoint: nth($breakpoint-content, 1);   
      $col-count: nth($breakpoint-content, 2);
      $prefix: $breakpoint-name;
      
      @if unit($breakpoint) != "" {
        @error 'Breakpoints should not be backed up by a unit. But "#{$breakpoint-name}" in map: #{"$" + "breakpoints"} is backed up by a unit';
      }
      
      @media (min-width: #{$breakpoint}px) {
        @each $breakpoint-nameC, $breakpoint-contentC in $breakpoints {  
          $col-countC: nth($breakpoint-contentC, 2);
          $prefixC: $breakpoint-nameC;
          
          @for $iC from 1 through $col-countC {
            @if $col-count < $iC {
              @include permanent-grid-cols($prefixC, $iC, $iC);
            }
          }
        }
        
        @for $i from 1 through $col-count {
          @include permanent-grid-cols($prefix, $i, $col-count);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

This is a fraction of what it compiles to:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  body .lg\3A col\3A 9 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  body .lg\3A col\3A 10 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  body .lg\3A col\3A 11 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  body .lg\3A col\3A 12 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  body .xl\3A col\3A 9 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  body .xl\3A col\3A 10 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  body .xl\3A col\3A 11 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  body .xl\3A col\3A 12 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  body .xxl\3A col\3A 9 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  body .xxl\3A col\3A 10 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  body .xxl\3A col\3A 11 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  body .xxl\3A col\3A 12 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
  body .md\3A col\3A 1 {
    flex: 0 0 12.5vw;
    max-width: 12.5vw;
  }
  body .md\3A col\3A 2 {
    flex: 0 0 25vw;
    max-width: 25vw;
  }
  body .md\3A col\3A 3 {
    flex: 0 0 37.5vw;
    max-width: 37.5vw;
  }
  body .md\3A col\3A 4 {
    flex: 0 0 50vw;
    max-width: 50vw;
  }
  body .md\3A col\3A 5 {
    flex: 0 0 62.5vw;
    max-width: 62.5vw;
  }
  body .md\3A col\3A 6 {
    flex: 0 0 75vw;
    max-width: 75vw;
  }
  body .md\3A col\3A 7 {
    flex: 0 0 87.5vw;
    max-width: 87.5vw;
  }
  body .md\3A col\3A 8 {
    flex: 0 0 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: Im just curious, what's the purpose of using `:` in class names, other than one have to escape same later on in css?

Comment: XD. I usually use the `:` sign only in purly sass generated css, so I don't get a headache. @skobaljic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself, it was not about the `@media queries`, but the right loops and overwriting technique. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/RwajMjy).

**This**:

```
    @each $breakpoint-nameC, $breakpoint-contentC in $breakpoints {
              $col-countC: nth($breakpoint-contentC, 2);
              $prefixC: $breakpoint-nameC;

              @if $breakpoint-nameC != $breakpoint-name {
                @if $col-countC != $col-count {
                  @for $iC from 1 through ($col-countC - ($col-countC - $col-count)) {
                    @include permanent-grid-cols($prefixC, $iC, $col-countC - ($col-countC - $col-count));
                  }
                  
                  @for $iC from $col-count + 1 through $col-countC{
                    @include permanent-grid-cols($prefixC, $iC, $iC);
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

insted of this:

```
@media (min-width: #{$breakpoint}px) {
        @each $breakpoint-nameC, $breakpoint-contentC in $breakpoints {  
          $col-countC: nth($breakpoint-contentC, 2);
          $prefixC: $breakpoint-nameC;
          
          @for $iC from 1 through $col-countC {
            @if $col-count < $iC {
              @include permanent-grid-cols($prefixC, $iC, $iC);
            }
          }
        }
```